# Yum offline installation on rhel7.2 failed

Tags: yum, rhel7

I am trying to deploy my java server application on a client machine running Red Hat Linux 7.2 with no internet connection.

I managed to do it on my own test server in azure, several times, but the installation on the client machine failed.

### Preperation

Before installing on the client machine, I setup a RHEL 7.2 machine on Azure, gathered all the dependencies in a folder named rpms with `repotrack` command.

I used `sudo yum --nogpgcheck localinstall rpms/*.rpm` to install them on the machine. 
it worked on my machine :)

### `yum list installed` on my machine before installing:

http://pastebin.com/XXRjctKZ

### `yum list installed` on the client machine:

http://pastebin.com/DZp5rjRP

### The packages i'm trying to install :

```
acl-2.2.51-12.el7.x86_64.rpm
audit-libs-2.4.1-5.el7.x86_64.rpm
audit-libs-python-2.4.1-5.el7.x86_64.rpm
autoconf-2.69-11.el7.noarch.rpm
automake-1.13.4-3.el7.noarch.rpm
backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.5.0.1.tar.gz
basesystem-10.0-7.el7.noarch.rpm
bash-4.2.46-20.el7_2.x86_64.rpm
binutils-2.23.52.0.1-55.el7.x86_64.rpm
bison-2.7-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
bzip2-1.0.6-13.el7.x86_64.rpm
bzip2-libs-1.0.6-13.el7.x86_64.rpm
ca-certificates-2015.2.6-70.1.el7_2.noarch.rpm
checkpolicy-2.1.12-6.el7.x86_64.rpm
chkconfig-1.3.61-5.el7_2.1.x86_64.rpm
click-6.6.tar.gz
configobj-5.0.6.tar.gz
coreutils-8.22-15.el7_2.1.x86_64.rpm
cpio-2.11-24.el7.x86_64.rpm
cpp-4.8.5-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
cracklib-2.9.0-11.el7.x86_64.rpm
cracklib-dicts-2.9.0-11.el7.x86_64.rpm
cryptsetup-libs-1.6.7-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
curl-7.29.0-25.el7.x86_64.rpm
cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.26-20.el7_2.x86_64.rpm
dbus-1.6.12-14.el7_2.x86_64.rpm
dbus-libs-1.6.12-14.el7_2.x86_64.rpm
device-mapper-1.02.107-5.el7_2.5.x86_64.rpm
device-mapper-libs-1.02.107-5.el7_2.5.x86_64.rpm
devtoolset-3-elfutils-libelf-0.161-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
devtoolset-3-elfutils-libs-0.161-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
devtoolset-4-elfutils-libelf-0.166-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
devtoolset-4-elfutils-libs-0.166-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
devtoolset-4-runtime-4.1-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
diffutils-3.3-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
docker-compose
docker-compose-1.5.2.tar.gz
docker-engine-1.12.2-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
docker-engine-selinux-1.12.2-1.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
dockerpty-0.3.4.tar.gz
docker_py-1.10.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
docker_pycreds-0.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
docker.sh
docopt-0.6.2.tar.gz
dracut-033-360.el7_2.1.x86_64.rpm
dwz-0.11-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
elfutils-0.163-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
elfutils-libelf-0.163-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
elfutils-libs-0.163-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
enum34-1.1.6-py2-none-any.whl
epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
expat-2.1.0-8.el7.x86_64.rpm
file-5.11-31.el7.x86_64.rpm
file-libs-5.11-31.el7.x86_64.rpm
filesystem-3.2-20.el7.x86_64.rpm
findutils-4.5.11-5.el7.x86_64.rpm
flex-2.5.37-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
functools32-3.2.3-2.zip
gawk-4.0.2-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
gcc-4.8.5-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
gcc-c++-4.8.5-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
gdb-7.6.1-80.el7.x86_64.rpm
gdbm-1.10-8.el7.x86_64.rpm
gettext-0.18.2.1-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
gettext-libs-0.18.2.1-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
glib2-2.42.2-5.el7.x86_64.rpm
glibc-2.17-106.el7_2.8.x86_64.rpm
glibc-common-2.17-106.el7_2.8.x86_64.rpm
glibc-devel-2.17-106.el7_2.8.x86_64.rpm
glibc-headers-2.17-106.el7_2.8.x86_64.rpm
gmp-6.0.0-12.el7_1.x86_64.rpm
gnupg2-2.0.22-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
grep-2.20-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
groff-base-1.22.2-8.el7.x86_64.rpm
gzip-1.5-8.el7.x86_64.rpm
hardlink-1.0-19.el7.x86_64.rpm
hostname-3.13-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
htop-2.0.2-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
humanize-0.5.1.tar.gz
info-5.1-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
initscripts-9.49.30-1.el7_2.3.x86_64.rpm
iotop-0.6-2.el7.noarch.rpm
ipaddress-1.0.17-py2-none-any.whl
iproute-3.10.0-54.el7_2.1.x86_64.rpm
iptables-1.4.21-16.el7.x86_64.rpm
iptables-services-1.4.21-16.el7.x86_64.rpm
iputils-20121221-7.el7.x86_64.rpm
jre-8u102-linux-x64.rpm
jsonschema-2.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
kernel-headers-3.10.0-327.36.2.el7.x86_64.rpm
keyutils-libs-1.5.8-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
kmod-20-8.el7_2.x86_64.rpm
kmod-libs-20-8.el7_2.x86_64.rpm
kpartx-0.4.9-85.el7_2.6.x86_64.rpm
krb5-libs-1.13.2-12.el7_2.x86_64.rpm
libacl-2.2.51-12.el7.x86_64.rpm
libassuan-2.1.0-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
libattr-2.4.46-12.el7.x86_64.rpm
libblkid-2.23.2-26.el7_2.3.x86_64.rpm
libcap-2.22-8.el7.x86_64.rpm
libcap-ng-0.7.5-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
libcgroup-0.41-8.el7.x86_64.rpm
libcom_err-1.42.9-7.el7.x86_64.rpm
libcroco-0.6.8-5.el7.x86_64.rpm
libcurl-7.29.0-25.el7.x86_64.rpm
libdb-5.3.21-19.el7.x86_64.rpm
libdb-utils-5.3.21-19.el7.x86_64.rpm
libestr-0.1.10-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
libfastjson4-0.99.4-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
libffi-3.0.13-16.el7.x86_64.rpm
libgcc-4.8.5-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
libgcrypt-1.5.3-12.el7_1.1.x86_64.rpm
libgomp-4.8.5-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
libgpg-error-1.12-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
libgt-0.3.11-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
libidn-1.28-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
libmnl-1.0.3-7.el7.x86_64.rpm
libmount-2.23.2-26.el7_2.3.x86_64.rpm
libmpc-1.0.1-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
libnetfilter_conntrack-1.0.4-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
libnfnetlink-1.0.1-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
libpwquality-1.2.3-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
libseccomp-2.2.1-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
libselinux-2.2.2-6.el7.x86_64.rpm
libselinux-python-2.2.2-6.el7.x86_64.rpm
libselinux-utils-2.2.2-6.el7.x86_64.rpm
libsemanage-2.1.10-18.el7.x86_64.rpm
libsemanage-python-2.1.10-18.el7.x86_64.rpm
libsepol-2.1.9-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
libssh2-1.4.3-10.el7_2.1.x86_64.rpm
libstdc++-4.8.5-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
libstdc++-devel-4.8.5-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
libtasn1-3.8-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
libtool-2.4.2-21.el7_2.x86_64.rpm
libtool-ltdl-2.4.2-21.el7_2.x86_64.rpm
libunistring-0.9.3-9.el7.x86_64.rpm
libuser-0.60-7.el7_1.x86_64.rpm
libutempter-1.1.6-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
libuuid-2.23.2-26.el7_2.3.x86_64.rpm
libverto-0.2.5-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
libxml2-2.9.1-6.el7_2.3.x86_64.rpm
logrotate-3.8.6-7.el7_2.x86_64.rpm
lua-5.1.4-14.el7.x86_64.rpm
m4-1.4.16-10.el7.x86_64.rpm
make-3.82-21.el7.x86_64.rpm
mcstrans-0.3.4-5.el7.x86_64.rpm
mpfr-3.1.1-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
ncurses-5.9-13.20130511.el7.x86_64.rpm
ncurses-base-5.9-13.20130511.el7.noarch.rpm
ncurses-libs-5.9-13.20130511.el7.x86_64.rpm
nspr-4.11.0-1.el7_2.x86_64.rpm
nss-3.21.0-9.el7_2.x86_64.rpm
nss-softokn-3.16.2.3-14.2.el7_2.x86_64.rpm
nss-softokn-freebl-3.16.2.3-14.2.el7_2.x86_64.rpm
nss-sysinit-3.21.0-9.el7_2.x86_64.rpm
nss-tools-3.21.0-9.el7_2.x86_64.rpm
nss-util-3.21.0-2.2.el7_2.x86_64.rpm
openldap-2.4.40-9.el7_2.x86_64.rpm
p11-kit-0.20.7-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
p11-kit-trust-0.20.7-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
pam-1.1.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64.rpm
patch-2.7.1-8.el7.x86_64.rpm
pcre-8.32-15.el7_2.1.x86_64.rpm
perl-5.16.3-286.el7.x86_64.rpm
perl516-perl-5.16.3-19.el7.x86_64.rpm
perl516-perl-Carp-1.32-3.el7.noarch.rpm
perl516-perl-constant-1.23-19.el7.noarch.rpm
perl516-perl-Encode-2.57-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
perl516-perl-Exporter-5.66-19.el7.noarch.rpm
perl516-perl-File-Path-2.08.01-19.el7.noarch.rpm
perl516-perl-File-Temp-0.22-19.el7.noarch.rpm
perl516-perl-Filter-1.49-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
perl516-perl-Getopt-Long-2.38-19.el7.noarch.rpm
perl516-perl-HTTP-Tiny-0.017-19.el7.noarch.rpm
perl516-perl-libs-5.16.3-19.el7.x86_64.rpm
perl516-perl-macros-5.16.3-19.el7.x86_64.rpm
perl516-perl-parent-0.228-1.el7.noarch.rpm
perl516-perl-PathTools-3.40-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
perl516-perl-Pod-Escapes-1.04-19.el7.noarch.rpm
perl516-perl-podlators-2.5.3-2.el7.noarch.rpm
perl516-perl-Pod-Perldoc-3.20-4.el7.noarch.rpm
perl516-perl-Pod-Simple-3.28-293.el7.noarch.rpm
perl516-perl-Pod-Usage-1.63-2.el7.noarch.rpm
perl516-perl-Scalar-List-Utils-1.31-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
perl516-perl-Socket-2.013-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
perl516-perl-Storable-2.34-19.el7.x86_64.rpm
perl516-perl-Text-ParseWords-3.27-19.el7.noarch.rpm
perl516-perl-threads-1.89-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
perl516-perl-threads-shared-1.43-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
perl516-perl-Time-Local-1.2000-19.el7.noarch.rpm
perl516-runtime-1.1-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
perl-Carp-1.26-244.el7.noarch.rpm
perl-constant-1.27-2.el7.noarch.rpm
perl-Data-Dumper-2.145-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
perl-Encode-2.51-7.el7.x86_64.rpm
perl-Exporter-5.68-3.el7.noarch.rpm
perl-File-Path-2.09-2.el7.noarch.rpm
perl-File-Temp-0.23.01-3.el7.noarch.rpm
perl-Filter-1.49-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
perl-Getopt-Long-2.40-2.el7.noarch.rpm
perl-HTTP-Tiny-0.033-3.el7.noarch.rpm
perl-libs-5.16.3-286.el7.x86_64.rpm
perl-macros-5.16.3-286.el7.x86_64.rpm
perl-parent-0.225-244.el7.noarch.rpm
perl-PathTools-3.40-5.el7.x86_64.rpm
perl-Pod-Escapes-1.04-286.el7.noarch.rpm
perl-podlators-2.5.1-3.el7.noarch.rpm
perl-Pod-Perldoc-3.20-4.el7.noarch.rpm
perl-Pod-Simple-3.28-4.el7.noarch.rpm
perl-Pod-Usage-1.63-3.el7.noarch.rpm
perl-Scalar-List-Utils-1.27-248.el7.x86_64.rpm
perl-Socket-2.010-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
perl-srpm-macros-1-8.el7.noarch.rpm
perl-Storable-2.45-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
perl-Test-Harness-3.28-3.el7.noarch.rpm
perl-Text-ParseWords-3.29-4.el7.noarch.rpm
perl-Thread-Queue-3.02-2.el7.noarch.rpm
perl-threads-1.87-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
perl-threads-shared-1.43-6.el7.x86_64.rpm
perl-Time-HiRes-1.9725-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
perl-Time-Local-1.2300-2.el7.noarch.rpm
pgcli-1.2.0.tar.gz
pgspecial-1.6.0.tar.gz
pinentry-0.8.1-14.el7.x86_64.rpm
pkgconfig-0.27.1-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
policycoreutils-2.2.5-20.el7.x86_64.rpm
policycoreutils-newrole-2.2.5-20.el7.x86_64.rpm
policycoreutils-python-2.2.5-20.el7.x86_64.rpm
popt-1.13-16.el7.x86_64.rpm
postgresql-9.2.15-1.el7_2.x86_64.rpm
postgresql-devel-9.2.15-1.el7_2.x86_64.rpm
postgresql-libs-9.2.15-1.el7_2.x86_64.rpm
procps-ng-3.3.10-5.el7_2.x86_64.rpm
prompt_toolkit-1.0.8-py2-none-any.whl
psycopg2-2.6.2.tar.gz
pth-2.0.7-23.el7.x86_64.rpm
Pygments-2.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
python-2.7.5-39.el7_2.x86_64.rpm
python27-python-2.7.8-16.el7.x86_64.rpm
python27-python-libs-2.7.8-16.el7.x86_64.rpm
python27-runtime-1.1-25.el7.x86_64.rpm
python-backports-1.0-6.el7.noarch.rpm
python-backports-1.0-8.el7.x86_64.rpm
python-backports-ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-4.el7.noarch.rpm
python-devel-2.7.5-39.el7_2.x86_64.rpm
python-IPy-0.75-6.el7.noarch.rpm
python-libs-2.7.5-39.el7_2.x86_64.rpm
python-pip-7.1.0-1.el7.noarch.rpm
python-setuptools-0.9.8-4.el7.noarch.rpm
PyYAML-3.12.tar.gz
qrencode-libs-3.4.1-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
readline-6.2-9.el7.x86_64.rpm
redhat-release-server-7.2-9.el7.x86_64.rpm
redhat-rpm-config-9.1.0-68.el7.noarch.rpm
requests-2.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
rpm-4.11.3-17.el7.x86_64.rpm
rpm-build-4.11.3-17.el7.x86_64.rpm
rpm-build-libs-4.11.3-17.el7.x86_64.rpm
rpm-libs-4.11.3-17.el7.x86_64.rpm
rpm-sign-4.11.3-17.el7.x86_64.rpm
rsyslog-8.22.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
rsyslog.repo
scl-utils-20130529-17.el7_1.x86_64.rpm
sed-4.2.2-5.el7.x86_64.rpm
selinux-policy-3.13.1-60.el7_2.9.noarch.rpm
selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-60.el7_2.9.noarch.rpm
selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-60.el7_2.9.noarch.rpm
selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-60.el7_2.9.noarch.rpm
setools-libs-3.3.7-46.el7.x86_64.rpm
setproctitle-1.1.10.tar.gz
setup-2.8.71-6.el7.noarch.rpm
shadow-utils-4.1.5.1-18.el7.x86_64.rpm
shared-mime-info-1.1-9.el7.x86_64.rpm
six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
sqlite-3.7.17-8.el7.x86_64.rpm
sqlparse-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
systemd-219-19.el7_2.13.x86_64.rpm
systemd-libs-219-19.el7_2.13.x86_64.rpm
sysvinit-tools-2.88-14.dsf.el7.x86_64.rpm
tar-1.26-29.el7.x86_64.rpm
texttable-0.8.5.tar.gz
tzdata-2016g-2.el7.noarch.rpm
unzip-6.0-15.el7.x86_64.rpm
ustr-1.0.4-16.el7.x86_64.rpm
util-linux-2.23.2-26.el7_2.3.x86_64.rpm
wcwidth-0.1.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
websocket_client-0.37.0.tar.gz
xz-5.1.2-12alpha.el7.x86_64.rpm
xz-libs-5.1.2-12alpha.el7.x86_64.rpm
zip-3.0-10.el7.x86_64.rpm
zlib-1.2.7-15.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

### The Error

The Client machine has an older RHEL 7.2 version, and therefore has different versions of most packages.

running `sudo yum --nogpgcheck localinstall rpms/*.rpm` the client machine with the following error:

```
Error: 
 Package:
  7:device-mapper-event-1.02.107-5.el7_2.1.x86_64 (@rhel-7-server-rpms)
 Requires:
  device-mapper = 7:1.02.107-5.el7_2.1 
 Removing:
  7:device-mapper-1.02.107-5.el7_2.1.x86_64 (@rhel-7-server-rpms) device-mapper = 7:1.02.107-5.el7_2.1 
Updated By: 
  7:device-mapper-1.02.107-5.el7_2.5.x86_64 (/device-mapper-1.02.107-5.el7_2.5.x86_64) 
  device-mapper = 7:1.02.107-5.el7_2.5
 Available:
   7:device-mapper-1.02.84-14.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) device-mapper = 7:1.02.84-14.el7
 Available:
   7:device-mapper-1.02.93-3.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)  device-mapper = 7:1.02.93-3.el7
 Available:
   7:device-mapper-1.02.93-3.el7_1.1.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) device-mapper = 7:1.02.93-3.el7_1.1
 Available:
   7:device-mapper-1.02.107-5.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) device-mapper = 7:1.02.107-5.el7 

Error:
 Package:
   dracut-config-rescue-033-360.el7_2.x86_64 (@rhel-7-server-rpms)
 Requires:
   dracut = 033-360.el7_2 
 Removing:
   dracut-033-360.el7_2.x86_64 (@rhel-7-server-rpms)  dracut = 033-360.el7_2
 Updated By:
   dracut-033-360.el7_2.1.x86_64 (/dracut-033-360.el7_2.1.x86_64) dracut = 033-360.el7_2.1 
 Available: 
  dracut-033-161.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) dracut = 033-161.el7 
 Available:
   dracut-033-161.el7_0.173.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) dracut = 033-161.el7_0.173
 Available:
   dracut-033-240.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) dracut = 033-240.el7 
 Available:
   dracut-033-241.el7_1.1.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) dracut = 033-241.el7_1.1
 Available:
   dracut-033-241.el7_1.3.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) dracut = 033-241.el7_1.3 
 Available:
   dracut-033-241.el7_1.5.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) dracut = 033-241.el7_1.5 
 Available:
   dracut-033-359.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) dracut = 033-359.el7

 Error: Package: systemd-sysv-219-19.el7_2.7.x86_64 (@rhel-7-server-rpms) 
 Requires: 
   systemd = 219-19.el7_2.7 
 Removing:
   systemd-219-19.el7_2.7.x86_64 (@rhel-7-server-rpms) systemd = 219-19.el7_2.7 
 Updated By:
   systemd-219-19.el7_2.13.x86_64 (/systemd-219-19.el7_2.13.x86_64) systemd = 219-19.el7_2.13 
 Available:
   systemd-208-11.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) systemd = 208-11.el7 
 Available:
   systemd-208-11.el7_0.2.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) systemd = 208-11.el7_0.2 
 Available:
   systemd-208-11.el7_0.4.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) systemd = 208-11.el7_0.4 
 Available:
   systemd-208-11.el7_0.5.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) systemd = 208-11.el7_0.5
 Available:
   systemd-208-11.el7_0.6.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) systemd = 208-11.el7_0.6
 Available:
   systemd-208-20.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) systemd = 208-20.el7
 Available:
   systemd-208-20.el7_1.2.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) systemd = 208-20.el7_1.2
 Available:
   systemd-208-20.el7_1.3.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) systemd = 208-20.el7_1.3 
 Available:
   systemd-208-20.el7_1.5.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) systemd = 208-20.el7_1.5 
 Available:
  systemd-208-20.el7_1.6.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) systemd = 208-20.el7_1.6
 Available: 
  systemd-219-19.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) systemd = 219-19.el7 
 Available:
  systemd-219-19.el7_2.4.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) systemd = 219-19.el7_2.4 

Error: 
 Package:
  glibc-2.17-106.el7_2.4.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms) 
Requires:
  glibc-common = 2.17-106.el7_2.4
 Removing:
  glibc-common-2.17-106.el7_2.4.x86_64 (@rhel-7-server-rpms) glibc-common = 2.17-106.el7_2.4 
Updated By:
  glibc-common-2.17-106.el7_2.8.x86_64 (/glibc-common-2.17-106.el7_2.8.x86_64)
  glibc-common = 2.17-106.el7_2.8
 Available:
  glibc-common-2.17-55.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) glibc-common = 2.17-55.el7 
 Available:
   glibc-common-2.17-55.el7_0.1.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) glibc-common = 2.17-55.el7_0.1
 Available:
   glibc-common-2.17-55.el7_0.3.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) glibc-common = 2.17-55.el7_0.3
 Available:
   glibc-common-2.17-55.el7_0.5.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) glibc-common = 2.17-55.el7_0.5 
 Available:
   glibc-common-2.17-78.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) glibc-common = 2.17-78.el7 
 Available:
   glibc-common-2.17-105.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) glibc-common = 2.17-105.el7 
 Available: 
  glibc-common-2.17-106.el7_2.1.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) glibc-common = 2.17-106.el7_2.1 

Error: 
  Package: dracut-network-033-360.el7_2.x86_64 (@rhel-7-server-rpms) 
 Requires:
   dracut = 033-360.el7_2
 Removing:
   dracut-033-360.el7_2.x86_64 (@rhel-7-server-rpms) dracut = 033-360.el7_2 
 Updated By:
   dracut-033-360.el7_2.1.x86_64  (/dracut-033-360.el7_2.1.x86_64) dracut = 033-360.el7_2.1
 Available:
   dracut-033-161.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) dracut = 033-161.el7
 Available:
   dracut-033-161.el 7_0.173.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) dracut = 033-161.el7_0.173
 Available:
  dracut-033-240.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) dracut = 033-240.el7
 Available:
  dracut-033-241.el7_1.1.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) dracut = 033-241.el7_1.1
 Available:
  dracut-033-241.el7_1.3.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) dracut = 033-241.el7_1.3 
 Available:
  dracut-033-241.el7_1.5.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) dracut = 033-241.el7_1.5
 Available:
  dracut-033-359.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms) dracut = 033-359.el7
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

### What I tried

- Disabling the existing repositories on the machine so it won't try to connect to it.
- `yum localupdate` to update the packages.
- `yum localinstall` and `yum localupdate` of a single rpm.

### What I don't understand:

1. why `localinstall` or `localupdate` did not let me install the packages.
2. what can I do to reslove this issue.

Comment: All of your errors are clearly because of missing dependencies.  You need to address that.

Comment: Right. You haven't downloaded all the RPMs you need.

Comment: @michaelHampton I still don't understand what the error message is saying or what missing dependencies I have. for example, the first error complains about package device-mapper-event, as a dependency of device-mapper. I have included an rpm for device-mapper, but failed to supply an rpm for one of it's dependencies - namely device-mapper-event ? is that correct ?

Comment: @yoonix can you explain what the error messages suggest that I do or what package is missing?

Comment: @Liron That's correct, you need the device-mapper-event RPM, and all the rest.

Comment: @MichaelHampton can you point out why `repotrack` failed to download these packages ?